# FLUTTER scroll controller is throwing stack overflow error when using jumpTo method

Tags: scroll, dart, controller, flutter, synchronization

i'm trying to move two scrolls together in sync,
and i managed to move them using one but not the other.

i was using the `controller`'s `jumpTo` method to set the other's `offset`.
but i'm getting a `stack overflow` error if i touch the other scroll.

in my example (below), it's fine if i scroll through the "`MOVE`".
but AS SOON AS I TOUCH THE "`FOLLOW`", it gives me an error and i have to restart the app.

what is the explanation behind this?
how do i fix this?

ultimately i want to have MANY scrolls that can move like this,
but i need to have the "`TEXT HERE`" not moving in between each of them.

below are my whole `main.dart`,
please give it a try.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  var c1 = ScrollController(); // controller declaration
  var c2 = ScrollController();



  @override void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('start');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('data test'),
      ),

      body: new Container( //===================================
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        color: Colors.blue[100],
        height: 200,

        child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('SOME TEXT HERE'),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                controller: c1, // KONTROLER
                child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.green[100], child: Row( children: <Widget>[
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('+MOOOVE        -')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-MOOOVE        -')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-MOOOVE        -')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('*MOOOVE        *')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-MOOOVE        -')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-MOOOVE        -')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-MOOOVE        +')),

                ],),)
              ),
              Text('ANOTHER TEXT HERE'),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                controller: c2, // KONTROLER
                child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red[100], child: Row(children: <Widget>[

                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('+        FOLLOW-')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-        FOLLOW-')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-        FOLLOW-')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('*        FOLLOW*')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-        FOLLOW-')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-        FOLLOW-')),
                  Container(width: 100,child: Text('-        FOLLOW+')),
                ],),)
              ),
          ]),


          onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollinfo) {  // HEY!! LISTEN!!

            c2.jumpTo( c1.offset ); // c1 is controlling c2's offset

            print('OFFSET--'+c1.offset.toInt().toString()+"--"+c2.offset.toInt().toString());
          },
        )
      ), // ===================
    );
  }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: The issue is because you combine `ScrollNotification` with `ScrollController`, the `jumpTo` triggers the `ScrollNotification`, which in turn triggers `jumpTo` so that's why you get the SO error. You should check the `ScrollController.addListener` which is triggered when you scroll :).

Comment: can you give me an example for how to fix my code above? where do i put the `.addListener`? should i still be using the `onNotification`?

Comment: @danypata or maybe, is it possible to have 1 `controller` to control both scrolls?

Comment: i tried using `TrackingScrollController` but it is not working at all.

Comment: i gave you a working code, didn't i? it used two lists and you could scroll any of them and the other list followed it

Comment: @pskink didnt you delete it? it was working before because the following list was stacked behind. if i were to put them side by side, the other would give me an error

Comment: no they were side by side - it used `level` variable incremented and decremented before/after calling `otherController.jumpTo` method

Answer (score 0):

So what I suggest is using `ScrollController`([docs here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html)). And here is a code snipped on how to use them.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      ScrollController firstScroll = ScrollController();
      ScrollController secondScrollController = ScrollController();

      @override
      void initState() {
         super.initState();
         firstScroll.addListener(() {
        //THIS IS called when scroll is triggered, but it might be called for other events
            secondScrollController
               .jumpTo(firstScroll.offset); // THIS will sync the scroll;
         });
       }

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SingleChildScrollView(
                 // this is the first scroll
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    controller: firstScroll, // THIS IS THE FIRST SCROLL CONTROLLER
                    child: Container(
                       //TODO: add your content here here
                    ),
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                   controller: secondScrollController,
                   // HERE YOU SET THE SECOND CONTROLLER
                   child: Container(
                      //TODO: add your content here
                   ),
                 )
            ],
        ),
     );
  }
}
```

Note the code is just a snippet on how you can forward the scroll from one scroll widget to another. You can then implement any logic you want in the scroll listener body.

Comment: this is exactly what i have done, but if i move the second scroll, the first scroll will not follow. AND if i add a listener to the second scroll, then both scroll will drag each other because they keep overwriting their offsets and its stuttering like hell.

Comment: hey Chris do u found the answer for this. I am facing similar Issue.